# Assign prop values when doing a default export in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having such a pain with such a small issue. I am integrating Launch Darkly which takes a certain number of parameters for it work during the export. My export is as follows:

```
export default withLDProvider({
    clientSideID,
    user: {
      key: userId,
      custom: {
        siteId: site,
      },
    },
  })(App);
```

Now, clientSideID, userId, and site are part of my props which i need to assign to it.

I have tried the following:

```
export default (props) => {
  const { auth: { userId, site } } = props.store.getState();

  return withLDProvider({
    clientSideID,
    user: {
      key: userId,
      custom: {
        siteId: site,
      },
    },
  })(App);
};
```

but i get the following error:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in Component (created by Connect(Component))
    in Connect(Component) (created by HotExportedConnect(Component))
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedConnect(Component))
    in HotExportedConnect(Component) (at src/index.js:33)
    in ErrorBoundary (at src/index.js:33)
```

help?

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused, are you trying to create a component or a function? If you are creating a function, then you would not be sending props to it. If you are creating a component (call it like: `<withLDProvider props={x} />`), then maybe this will do what you want:

```
import React from "react";

const withLDProvider = props => {
    const { userId, site } = props;
    return (
        {
            clientSideID,
            user: {
                key: userId,
                custom: {
                    siteId: site,
                },
            },
        }
    )
}

export default withLDProvider;
```